# PX-REM mixin only working with font-sizing

Tags: css, sass, mixins

So I am using this mixin to generate px value fallbacks when using the rem unit:

```
@function fix8_unit_to_px($val) {
    @if unitless($val) {
        @if $val == 0 {
            @return $val
        } @else {
            @return $val * 10+px
        };
    } @else { @return $val};
}

@function fix8_unit_to_rem($val) {
    @if unitless($val) {
        @if $val == 0 {
            @return $val
        } @else {
            @return $val+rem
        };
    } @else { @return $val};
}

@mixin rem($prop, $val...) {
    $n: length($val);
    $i: 1;

    $px-list: ();
    $rem-list: ();

    @while $i <= $n {
        $px-list: append($px-list, fix8_unit_to_px(nth($val, $i)));
        $rem-list: append($rem-list, fix8_unit_to_rem(nth($val, $i)));
        $i: $i + 1;
    }

    @if $px-list == $rem-list {     /* 8 */
        #{$prop}: $px-list;  /* 9 */
    } @else {
       #{$prop}: $px-list;  /* 9 */
       #{$prop}: $rem-list; /* 9 */
    }
}
```

This works if I use it on font-sizing i.e.

```
@include rem(font-sizing, 1.4);
```

returns

```
font-sizing: 14px;
font-sizing: 1.4rem;
```

However if I use it for anything other than font-sizing, it only returns the rem value:

```
@include rem(margin-top, 1.4);
```

returns

```
margin-top: 1.4rem;
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://sassmeister.com/gist/391804328a642afc84a7

Comment: Could this be an issue with Sass or ruby? So confused

Comment: Sassmeister is using the Ruby version of Sass...

Comment: I've tested it with Grunt and Gulp and get the same result so it can't be them. My Sass verison is 3.4.5 (Selective steve) which also shouldn't be the issue. The only thing I can think of which may be causing it is Ruby (sassmeister is using Ruby 2.0.0 and I'm running 2.1.1p76). Hmm